# rounding corners on the background?

Tags: html, css

Im wondering if its possible to round corners just on the background of the page, so for example -

```
body{background-color:#7A991A;
```

so I would like to round each corner of the page?
thank youu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to give the `html` element a background color:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
html { background: white }
body {
    background-color:#7A991A;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wYKa3/

Comment: This is good but make sure you don't have padding on `body`. Also I thought it looked a bit better if I set body height: 99% or 98%, leaving html at 100%

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
body{
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background:#7A991A;
}
```

it's a background with rounded and shaddaw color corners.

Comment: +1 because you can indeed do this. However note that some older browsers may not like you trying to round the corners of the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius`, like so:

```
body {
    background-color:#7A991A;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

To increase compatibility with different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this **CSS** with browsers compatibility level:

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: white
}

body {
-moz-border-radius:20px;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
border-radius: 20px;
background:red;
}
```

demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/trzpK/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this's possible. Since "body" is the entire document, then if you round corners of the page, what should appear underneath?

Maybe you can just wrap page content in a `<div>` element which will have full width and full height, and then you set rounded corners on it instead of body. Then you set body's background to a color different to that of the full-size div and you're set. Something like this should work:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- Your content here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body { background-color: #000000; }
#content { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```